# is it possible too hook the android gsm modem using C

Tags: android, c, linux

We want to make a custom dialer for android .Is it possible to do this by directly sending the At commands to the modem which in my case is in dev/smd0

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that this is possible on most phones. I haven't used it to make phone calls from within the phone (I have done a lot of calls via USB as part of an audio testing project).